# Let $f$ and $g$ linear operators where $f$ and $g$ commute and $f$ has simple spectrumm, then there is $P$ a polynomial such thah $g=P(f)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $f : \mathbb{C}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a linear operator with  a simple spectrum, furthermore, let $g : \mathbb{C}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n
$ be a linear operator such that  $f$ and $g$ commute.

Show that there is $P$ a polynomial such that $g=P(f)$.

**Remark:** The spectrum is simple when the characteristic polynomial has not multiple roots.

Comment: what do you mean by characteristic polynomial of $f$ where $f:\mathbb {C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb C$

Comment: You're right, already I corrected the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the characteristic polynomial of $f$ has no multiple roots, then there exist distinct complex numbers $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ and a basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that
$$
fv_k = \lambda_k v_k
$$
for $k = 1, \dots, n$. Now
\begin{align*}
f(gv_k) &= g(fv_k) \\
&= \lambda_k (gv_k),
\end{align*}
which means that $gv_k$ is in the eigenspace of $f$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. This implies that there exists $\alpha_k \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$gv_k = \alpha_k v_k.
$$
Now let $P$ be a polynomial such that
$$
P(\lambda_k) = \alpha_k
$$
for $k = 1, \dots, n$. Then
\begin{align*}
\bigl( P(f) \bigr) v_k &= P(\lambda_k) v_k \\
&= \alpha_k v_k \\
&= gv_k
\end{align*}
for $k = 1, \dots, n$. Because $P(f)$ and $g$ agree on a basis, we conclude that $P(f) = g$, as desired.